# Extracting and Storing Value of a Initial Header in NGINX

Tags: nginx, jwt, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am running Grafana behind an NGINX reverse proxy to address certain scenarios that Grafana alone cannot handle. One such scenario occurs when a user logs into Grafana using a JWT (JSON Web Token) via URL login and then navigates to other pages within Grafana (e.g., the profile page). If the user refreshes the page, they are unexpectedly logged out and redirected to the login screen. To prevent this behavior and for some other reasons, I've set up NGINX as a reverse proxy in front of Grafana, along with a proxy login application.

Here’s how the flow works:

- The user enters their username and password in the proxy login application.
- Upon successful login, the application generates a JWT with an expiration date.
- The application sends this JWT in the X-JWT-Assertion header by making an initial GET request to NGINX.
- Application then redirects the user to Grafana, user logs in to Grafana by URL login using JWT.

My goal is to store the JWT token permanently and append it to subsequent requests in the URL using proxy_redirect. This way, even if the user refreshes a page in Grafana, the session won’t end due to the presence of the token in the URL.

The challenge lies in handling dynamic tokens. Hard-coding the token directly in the configuration works, but since the token changes with each login, I need a more flexible solution.To achieve this, I'm thinking about extracting value of X-JWT-Assertion header from initial GET request before redirecting to Grafana and store it permanently somehow. Is it possible? If it is, how can I achieve that? I tried some possible rules to achieve it but couldn't succeed. If it is not possible, how can I achieve my end goal?

Feel free to ask if you need further assistance or clarification. Thanks in advance.

Here is the current configuration (proxy_redirect is incomplete for now, there should be stored JWT after `?auth_token=`):

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

upstream grafana {
  server localhost:32301;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; 

    location / {
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
    
     rewrite  ^/(.*)  /$1 break;
     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
     proxy_set_header X-REAL-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prote $scheme;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_pass http://grafana;
     proxy_redirect ~^(/[^\/?]+)(/[^?]+)?(\?)?(.*)$ $1$2?auth_token=&$4;
}

    location /api/live/ {

     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-JWT-Assertion' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;  
    }


   
    rewrite  ^/(.*)  /$1 break; 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_pass http://grafana/;
   }

 }
```